# Android Jetpack compose problem after few time app auto adding intent-filter to MainActivty even other activity have intent-filter in manifest

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am beginner in jetpack compose and I made simple switch button and toolBar (MainActivity) as below code showing which is working fine. I also made second activity which is simple login layout and many more activities which are also working fine but the problem is when i launch other activity rather than MainActivity it is showing only for few hours after that again Mainactivity appearing in my display no matter which activity have intent-filter after few hours my app is taking MainActivty as launch activity.

MainActivity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidJetpackComposePracticeTheme {
                Scaffold(topBar = {

                    TopAppBar(
                        title = {
                            Text(text = "Hello Jetpack")
                        },
                        navigationIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu")
                            }
                        },
                        actions = {

                            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Filled.Notifications,
                                    contentDescription = "Notifications"
                                )
                            }

                            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                                Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = "Search")
                            }

                        },
                        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)
                    )

                }, floatingActionButton = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
                    }
                }) {

                    ShowSwitch()

                }
            }
        }
    }

@Composable
fun ShowSwitch() {

    val isChecked = remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    Switch(checked = isChecked.value,
        onCheckedChange = {
            isChecked.value = it
        }, modifier = Modifier.run {
            size(20.dp)
            padding(top = 70.dp, start = 30.dp)
        })

}
```

As I said, I am beginner so I don't know what to do and please let me know is this my fault or am i missing something or this is bug?